# Trigger Engagement Plan for an email-id when Email is sent to an user

Tags: exm, engagement-plans

I am new to engagement plans and trying to setup one for a requirement, using Sitecore 8.1

**Requirement:**

1. Send an Offer Email with offer link to user email-id
2. Send a reminder email after 24 hours if the user does not respond to the Offer link provided in the email
3. Expire the Offer Link after 2 days

I am trying to achieve this using an Email Template/sitecore/templates/Email Campaign/Messages/AB Test Message and associating it with engagement plan.

When I try to send an email I get the below error:

*Failed to enroll a contact in the engagement plan.
*Exception: Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Exceptions.EmailCampaignException
Message: The automation state for contact 093523b5-9e57-4294-88a5-c5e92f3d7376 and plan bbbaa175-b07d-41b3-b0cc-d9a192376fef has not been found.*
(Guid contactId, DispatchQueueItem dispatchQueueItem, Guid planId, String stateName, ExmCustomValues customValues)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
MessageTaskRunner worker thread 4 16:38:08 ERROR Exception: Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Exceptions.NonCriticalException
Message: Recipient xdb:093523b5-9e57-4294-88a5-c5e92f3d7376 skipped. Failed to enroll its corresponding contact in the engagement plan.
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()*

Please let me know if I am missing anything to achieve the requirement.

[image: mailTemplate]

[image: Engagement Plan]

Comment: have you deployed the engagement plan to its workflow? see: https://www.screencast.com/t/ejXAYfGKsXy0

Comment: Yes, the engagement plan is deployed. I have tried to programmatically identify the user and enrolled the user to the engagement plan but still no luck.

Comment: I managed to get this working, the engagement plan associated to the email should have the default engagement plan states like  Invalid Address, Soft Bounce, Hard Bounce etc